# PHP displaying wrong custom taxonomy images

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm using the [Taxonomy Images plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/) to try to pull in the category images for custom categories on a page that displays all the categories my site has. For some reason, this code outputs the correct names and descriptions, but will only show one category image.

I'd like the images to do what the other category features do, populate with the appropriate data for each category and display all the categories on the page. If I use `echo wp_get_attachment_image( $imgs[$id], 'thumbnail' );` it publishes all of the images, but if I change that from `echo` to make it a variable, it only displays one image.

```
$imgs = get_option( 'taxonomy_image_plugin' );
$categories = get_terms('portfolio_category', array('orderby' => 'id', 'hide_empty' => 0));
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $id = $category->term_id;
    $img = wp_get_attachment_image( $imgs[$id], 'thumbnail' );
}
    for($i=0; $i<count($categories); $i++)
     {
     echo('<h2>'.$categories[$i]->name.'</h2>');
     echo($img);
     echo('<p>'.$categories[$i]->description.'</p>');
}
```

I guess that I'm just confused as how to add a counter like `[$i]` so that this code outputs the correct category images. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"...a page that displays the portfolio categories of a theme I've purchased..."* - Close-voted as **too localized**. As this is a commercial Theme, we don't have access to the source code to be able to help diagnose/resolve the issue. Have you tried the support offerings of the developer from whom you purchased the Theme?

Comment: I have been in contact with the support team, I've just found that Stack Exchange is faster and better with with this sort of stuff. I've provided all the code that should be necessary to debug my problem(hopefully), and the features that I'm using like get_terms() and Taxonomy Images are either open source plugins or built in to Wordpress, is there a way I could rephrase this question so that it can not be closed?

Comment: This line is the problem: **`$cats = pexeto_get_taxonomy_children('portfolio_category', $cat_id);`**. The `pexeto_get_taxonomy_children()` is a Theme function, not a core function.

Comment: I know, but that's the part that works. I'm trying to get the category descriptions and images to work. It's fine, I understand the protocol here and hopefully the people at pexeto can help me figure out my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Then can you edit your question to specify the *output* of that function? If so, then the rest of the question should involve only core functions. Also, clarify which functions are returning what you expect, and which ones *aren't*.

Comment: Can you highlight the code that outputs this, specifically: "*I'm trying to pull the descriptions with get_terms() and the images with get_option() that correlate with the proper categories, but they're only pulling one category description and one category image and using them on each of the categories.*", with an explanation of what it is *actually* returning, vs. what you *expect* it to return? Most of the rest of the code in your question isn't really relevant.

Comment: @ChipBennett I've edited the question and corresponding code down to the heart of the issue. I've removed all references to proprietary code. Hopefully this is up to par with what this community expects and I can get an answer.

Comment: Okay, I think it's much clearer now. :) One last thing (and this one, mainly because I'm not familiar with how your category images Plugin stores its database option: can you add the `var_dummp( $imgs )` output?

Comment: @chipbennett `var_dump($imgs)` outputs the following: `array(3) { [25]=> int(1055) [27]=> int(1094) [26]=> int(1095) }`

Comment: So `$imgs` is an assoicative array, in the form of `'$cat_id' => '$attachment_id'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chip was on the right path, but closing the first loop would only publish one category instead of every category. What I ended up doing was closing the first loop and calling the ID and the img inside the second loop.

```
$imgs = get_option( 'taxonomy_image_plugin' );
$categories = get_terms('portfolio_category', array('orderby' => 'id', 'hide_empty' => 0));
for($i=0; $i<count($categories); $i++)
    {
    $id=$categories[$i]->term_id;
    $img=wp_get_attachment_image($imgs[$id], 'thumbnail');
        echo('<h2>'.$categories[$i]->name.'</h2>');
        echo($img);
        echo('<p>'.$categories[$i]->description.'</p>');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* (at least part of) the problem is that you've got a nested loop where you don't really need one.

The output of [**`get_terms()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) is an *array of objects*. So `$categories` should be an array of objects.

You loop through this array of objects here:

```
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $id = $category->term_id;
    $img = wp_get_attachment_image( $imgs[$id], 'thumbnail' );
}
```

The problem is that you *close* that loop, and then loop through `$categories` a second time:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($categories); $i++)
     {
     echo('<h2>'.$categories[$i]->name.'</h2>');
     echo($img);
     echo('<p>'.$categories[$i]->description.'</p>');
}
```

The problem there, though, is that `$id` and `$img` will retain their value based on the *last* object in `$categories`.

I would recommend getting rid of the second loop, and doing everything in your original `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    // Set ID and IMG
    $id = $category->term_id;
    $img = wp_get_attachment_image( $imgs[$id], 'thumbnail' );

    // Output markup
     echo('<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>');
     echo($img);
     echo('<p>'.$category->description.'</p>');
}
```

That *should* fix the issues with out-of-sync looping, though I'm not *entirely* certain about `$img`, since I'm not familiar with the Plugin you're using and don't know how it saves its option to the database.

Comment: I need to keep the second loop open, because I'm trying to display all the categories I've created plus more in the future. So the `for($i=0; $i<count($categories); $i++)` loop is necessary on that end. The problem I'm having is getting the image based on the `$category->term_id;` for every category. [The page is here](http://client.analog.la/fotomoto/portfolio/) and hopefully seeing it will give you a general sense of what I'm trying to accomplish, just with different images on each category.

Comment: You're using this line to query all categories: `$categories = get_terms('portfolio_category', array('orderby' => 'id', 'hide_empty' => 0));` Why would that fail to query new categories that may be added in the future?

Comment: It's failing to add the rest of the categories that currently exist. This code only displays the last category. Although, all the information is correct, so that part is working finally!

Comment: I was able to figure it out thanks to your help. Kudos to you and your magnificent Wordpress savvy.